# How to multi-thread update a database that's updated by sql code?

Tags: java, sql, multithreading, spring-boot

I've made a basic CRUD spring-boot app that connects to a Postgresql DB.
I access the DB through sql code in my employeeDao, that is called later in the Controller through an employeeService class. 
I now have to update the DB using a multi-thread method, but i do not know how to implement that.

I've made a taskExecutor, but i don;t really know how to use it.

public Executor taskExecutor() {

```
    final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(50);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("EmployeeThread-");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

This is my EmployeeDaoImpl :

```
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao{

    public EmployeeDaoImpl(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template) {  
        this.template = template;  
}  
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template;  

    @Override
    public List<Employee> findAll() {
        return template.query("select * from employee", new EmployeeRowMapper());
    }
    @Override
    public void insertEmployee(Employee emp) {
         final String sql = "insert into employee(employeeId, employeeName ) values(:employeeId,:employeeName)";

            KeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
            SqlParameterSource param = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                    .addValue("employeeId", emp.getEmployeeId())
                    .addValue("employeeName", emp.getEmployeeName());
            template.update(sql,param, holder);

    }

    @Override
    public void updateEmployee(Employee emp) {
         final String sql = "update employee set employeeName=:employeeName where employeeId=:employeeId";

            KeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
            SqlParameterSource param = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                    .addValue("employeeId", emp.getEmployeeId())
                    .addValue("employeeName", emp.getEmployeeName());
            template.update(sql,param, holder);

    }

    @Override
    public void executeUpdateEmployee(Employee emp) {
         final String sql = "update employee set employeeName=:employeeName where employeeId=:employeeId";


         Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<String,Object>();  
         map.put("employeeId", emp.getEmployeeId());
         map.put("employeeName", emp.getEmployeeName());

         template.execute(sql,map,new PreparedStatementCallback<Object>() {  
                @Override  
                public Object doInPreparedStatement(PreparedStatement ps)  
                        throws SQLException, DataAccessException {  
                    return ps.executeUpdate();  
                }  
            });  


    }

    @Override
    public void deleteEmployee(Employee emp) {
         final String sql = "delete from employee where employeeId=:employeeId";


         Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<String,Object>();  
         map.put("employeeId", emp.getEmployeeId());

         template.execute(sql,map,new PreparedStatementCallback<Object>() {  
                @Override  
                public Object doInPreparedStatement(PreparedStatement ps)  
                        throws SQLException, DataAccessException {  
                    return ps.executeUpdate();  
                }  
            });  


    }

}
```

And this is my Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/postgressApp")
public class ApplicationController {

    @Resource 
    EmployeeService employeeService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/employeeList")
    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employeeService.findAll();

    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/createEmp")
    public void createEmployee(@RequestBody Employee emp) {
         employeeService.insertEmployee(emp);

    }
    @PutMapping(value = "/updateEmp")
    public void updateEmployee(@RequestBody Employee emp) {
         employeeService.updateEmployee(emp);

    }
    @PutMapping(value = "/executeUpdateEmp")
    public void executeUpdateEmployee(@RequestBody Employee emp) {
         employeeService.executeUpdateEmployee(emp);

    }

    @DeleteMapping(value = "/deleteEmpById")
    public void deleteEmployee(@RequestBody Employee emp) {
         employeeService.deleteEmployee(emp);

    }


}
```

Should i change my code to update the DB through another method like a Crud Repository ?

Answer (score 0):

Normally for a live application, the HttpRequests from the users can arrive in different threads. So, your ApplicationController will get called from many threads. You don't need to do much about multi-threading yourself.

For simulating that, you can use your executor service to call various ApplicationController methods from Runnables. Submit one runnable for each operation to the executor.

However, you have to be careful that the business logic allows that sequence of operations. For example, you cant update an employee before he/she has been created. Similarly, after deleting an employee you can't update him/her.

Or, you could make it a bit more ordered by making each runnable operate only on one employee, and do a sequence of operations sequentially.

For working with executor service, you may want to read up about submitTask, shutdownNow and awaitTermination: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Quicker introduction: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! My problem was that, in theory, i would have aprox 200 machines sending me 1 request / second in json format ( one of the crud operations) and i wanted to make that possible through threads accessing the database. Maybe a batch update would also work.